# angularJS executing directive in memory and geting innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive in angularJS as `<print-note print-data='printData' id='notePrintDiv'></print-note>` this directive will take some object and create a formatted html for printing, but I don't want to show the formatted html in my main html I want the formatted html for printout. so I was hopping if there is any way in angularJS where in I just create the element and pass the scope object to it like `angular.element("<print-note print-data='printData' id='notePrintDiv'></print-note>");` or any other way and get its innerHTML.

P.S. I can also achieve the same with making outer html of directive template as `display: none` but that seems to be a bit hacky way.

Comment: depends how you are setting print up. Using media print css is pretty normal html printing approach. If printing from different window it would be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service should be able to do this. Inject it in your controller where you have access to the scope (with `printData`).

```
var element = $compile('<print-note print-data="printData" id="notePrintDiv"></print-note>')($scope);
```

Comment: $compile is also sort of runtime addition and extra processing. In angular app simple things keep app perform faster.

Comment: If you put `<print-note>...</print-note>` in the HTML directly and hide it with `ng-show` it has to be compiled and linked anyway. I feel that hiding it is the "hacky" solution. Difference is though, and you're right in that, that this way it has to be compiled/linked every time. Anyway this is just a possible way of doing it. The question asker will decide which one is suitable for him/her.

Comment: Possibilites are always there but one has to choose what is good fit for the environment I technically believe AngularJS to be very slow-- thats why I find and suggest performance first solutions. :)

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon by using ```ng-show/hide``` we are actually using ```display: none``` by using ```$compile``` we explicitly compiling the html when needed and not at load of page there by reducing load time.

Comment: I spoke from technically perspective and put my experience but your choice mate!

Answer (score 0):

I had to achieve samething in a AngularJS app - I kept the directive for Print-Button and I kept `id` for the `div` or HTML block that was targeted to be printed and kept that `div/html` `ng-show=false`. I think it's one of the right way to get the required task done.